# Salesforce record being shared but not showing in share table

Tags: salesforce

I have a few instances of a record being shared to users but when I go to the sharing table that user does not show. What all sharing mechanisms can have this behavior? I have shared via apex and manual but they always show up on the share table. This is concerning because now I dont know who else may have access to records and it not show in the share table.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you go to table, you mean querying `AccountShare`, `CustomObject__Share` tables or checking in UI? The sharing may be done via group membership, roles, via being in a role above the record's owner... Plus things like user can be able to see the Contact because he owns a Case on which this contact is in the lookup. And then there are AccountTeams for example or users with "View All: Accounts", "View All Data", "Modify All Data" profile/permission set overrides...

In UI your best option is to switch to Classic UI, go to the record and click the "sharing" button (if it's not on the page layout - edit the layout to add it). And then - on the list click "Expand" to see details which user can see / edit the record and why. If the sharing button doesn't show even after checking the layout - it might be that sharing was disabled for this table, for example because it's a detail in master-detail relation. That's ok, go to the parent record and try same thing.

And for programmer approach - query https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm